# PHP - Combine two images vertically

Tags: php, image-processing

I am combining two images in my Laravel application, it works on my local machine. But the bottom image disappear on my Ubuntu Server. All images are less than 100kb. The memory limit is set to -1.

Note: Before it combine, I converted the top image to have same width of the bottom image.

```
$top_image_path = '/textImage.jpg';
$bottom_image_path = '/blueImage.jpg';

list($top_image_width, $top_image_height) = getimagesize($top_image_path);
list($bottom_image_width, $bottom_image_height) = getimagesize($bottom_image_path);

$merged_width = $bottom_image_width;
$merged_height = $top_image_height + $bottom_image_height;

$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor($merged_width, $merged_height);

imagealphablending($merged_image, false);
imagesavealpha($merged_image, true);

$img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($top_image_path);
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($bottom_image_path);

imagecopy($merged_image, $img1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $top_image_width, $top_image_height);
imagecopy($merged_image, $img2, 0, $bottom_image_width, 0, 0, $bottom_image_width, $bottom_image_height);

imagejpeg($merged_image, 'merged_image.jpg');
```

Result:

The output image on my local machine:
[image: successfully combined images]

The output image on Ubuntu Server: [image: unsuccessfully combined images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the line has an issue as following.

```
imagecopy($merged_image, $img2, 0, $top_image_height, 0, 0, $bottom_image_width, $bottom_image_height);
```